# Failed to connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDBgetaddrinfo enotfound nodesjs

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js, node-modules

I am connecting nodejs to SQL Server 2014; below is my configuration. Kindly anyone help solve this problem.

```
 var http = require('http');       
 var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
 var app = express();
 var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

 var sqlConfig = {
    server: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB',
    database: 'NodejsApp',
    user: 'ra',
    password: 'root@123',
    port: 1433
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

function makeconn() {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(sqlConfig);
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
makeconn();
```

When I run it, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: remove the `@` character from your password

Comment: @Karlos @ is included in password

Comment: You should not pass any port, localdb can be access only locally

Comment: @sepupic not working with or without port

Comment: maybe you should pass the name in other mode? "\" is missed in the name, look at the error: Failed to connect to (localdb)MSSQLLocaldb:1433, it's wrong, we already get rid of 1433 but "\" is still missing, maybe it's a special character in your language and should be doubled?

Comment: @sepupic i am passing same credentials to login in sqlserver   :/

Comment: @sepupic so what should i pass server name??

Comment: I don't told you about credentias, I told you about your SERVER NAME. it should be (localdb)**slash**MSSQLLocaldb (do you see slash in it)?

Comment: The error you've got says that you try to connect to (localdb)MSSQLLocaldb (without slash). I have no idea of your language, maybe slash is reserved character and you need escape characters to pass it

Comment: i solve it by reinstalling sqlserver and set default instant during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by reinstalling sqlserver and set default instant during installation